# Notation for the sample total variation

Tags: notation

Given a sample $x=(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, what is your favorite notation for the sum of squares $\sum (x_i -\bar x)^2$ ? I like to keep $s^2_x$ for the sample variance, and I wonder whether $ss^2_x$ is a nice notation for the sum of squares.

Now if there are two paired samples $x$ and $y$, how to denote $\sum(x_i-\bar x)(y_i - \bar y)$ (and by the way how do we call it) ? If we use $ss^2_x$ for the total variation, should we use $ss_{xy}$ or $ss^2_{xy}$ ?

Actually I'm currently writing a doc about Deming regression and here is an example of an expression using the above notations :
$$\frac{ss^2_x ss^2_y - ss^4_{xy}}{ss^4_{xy}}. $$
Strange for the eyes, no ? Moreover the first time I typed this expression I did a mistake by confusing $ss_{xy}$ and $ss^2_{xy}$.

What do you think about $v^2_x$ ?

Comment: I have seen lots of horrible notation in this territory. Composite symbols such as $ss$ are difficult to read, but if you are determined to use them roman ss is preferable and most of the precedents seem to use upper case, e.g. SS. An analogue is that exp is fine as a composite, while $exp$ is classifiable as learner error.

Comment: I'd add: best not to use such notation unless you use it a lot; best to use a distinctive font if you use it at all.

Comment: @NickCox Hello. Sometimes I use lower case / upper case to distinguish the observation and the random variable. That's why I'm not enthusiastic with regard to $SS$.

Comment: I sympathise. But I wouldn't want to combine this kind of notational distinction with that sort of discussion. BTW, I would classify myself as a regression-type person who finds much ANOVA literature unreadable because of its barbarous notation, like reading old FORTRAN programs or literature about Soviet planning.

Comment: @NickCox :-) I understand. That's also why I've opened this post :)

Comment: Capital $S$ is often used (sometimes $S^2$), with various subscripts, as are variations on "SS". See [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Solving_the_least_squares_problem) [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Examples) [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_deviations#Sample_variance) [4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_sum_of_squares#Partitioning_in_the_general_OLS_model) [5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance#Effect_size). I'm not a fan of "SS", but it and $S$ - while breaking the 'capitals are r.v.s' convention - won't go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the maths and stats degree I did, the sum of squares was represented by $S_{xx}$:

$$S_{xx} = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2$$

with an analogous formula for $S_{yy}$.

One nice aspect of this notation is that the sum of cross-products is denoted by $S_{xy}$:

$$S_{xy} = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})$$

For the sample mean and variance, we used $\bar{x}$ and $s^2$. For the mean of a random variable $X$ or of a population, $E(X)$ or $\mu$, and the for variance $V(X)$ or $\sigma^2$.

Comment: I agree this is a good notation except for the usage of lower/upper to distinguish observation/random variable. But actually when writing statistics I never use the distinction with lower/upper, I prefer $x^{\text{obs}}$ and $x$ (though this could cause problem when there is already an exponent). And for the sample variance, do you use $s^2_x$ ?

Comment: Yes, notation can be pretty awkward. I've looked up my university notes and amended my answer. I think I've used something like $x^i$ for individual observations, and the vector $\mathbf{x}$ for a set of observations. Certainly, $s^2_x$ would be fine for the sample variance. To be honest, so long as you define what you're doing and it's clear, any notation is going to be ok. (Except that using $\Sigma$ for a covariance matrix still confuses the heck out of me!)

Comment: Where are you guys from? I can't remember the last time I saw "obs" and "_i_" as superscripts; I always use them as subscripts.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio I'm from the UK. I don't know whether notation is a national thing however, and moreover I'm student of statistics and a professional software developer who uses statistics, rather than a professional statistician.